# Tail Recursion with continuation

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion, ml

How would you convert the following ML code to a tail recursive function? I have stared at it and tried to figure it out for a couple hours and I can't see how to.

```
datatype Tree = NULL | NODE of Tree*Tree | VAL of int;
fun dup(NULL) = NULL
 | dup(VAL(y)) = NODE(VAL(y),VAL(y))
 | dup(NODE(y1,y2)) = NODE(dup(y1), dup(y2));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforming to continuation-passing style is (relatively) straightforward here - the recursion is the tricky case.

Rewriting the right-hand side sometimes makes it easier to see a pattern.

```
| dup (NODE (y1, y2)) = let val left = dup y1
                            val right = dup y2
                        in
                            NODE (left, right)
```

We need to grab both `left` and `right` and combine them afterwards.
The difference in CPS is that we pass along a function that receives these values instead of receiving them directly, then we let the continuation that was given to us handle the result.

Naming the continuation "return", it can look like this:

```
fun dup_cont NULL return = return NULL (* Trivial *)
    (* duplicate the value and return it *)
  | dup_cont (VAL y) return = return (NODE (VAL y, VAL y))
    (* recurse, grab the result.
       recurse again, grab result.
       combine the two results and return *)
  | dup_cont (NODE (y1, y2)) return = 
        dup_cont y1 (fn left => dup_cont y2 (fn right => return (NODE (left, right))))
```